# In OpenSSL, if I decrypt using a wrong password it just tells "bad decrypt" without showing the output. Is there a way to show it anyway?

Tags: encryption, openssl

I encrypted a sample test file using:

```
openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -in test -nosalt -out encprova.aes128
```

Then, to decrypt:

```
openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -d -in encprova.aes128 -nosalt
```

and if I write the correct pw, it prints the correct content of "test". but if I write an incorrect pw, it prints:

```
bad decrypt
009E69DB997F0000:error:1C800064:Provider routines:ossl_cipher_unpadblock:bad decrypt:providers/implementations/ciphers/ciphercommon_block.c:124:
```

I understand that OpenSSL knows if a decryption goes well by just looking at the padding: if padding is not present that means that decryption went bad.

But is there a way to force OpenSSL to see the decrypted content anyway?

Comment: Why do you want to see unencrypted random data? If OpenSSL cannot decrypt the data, then the encrypted data, would be the output? Your desire to see the encrypted data, when the decryption fails, does not make sense.

Comment: @Ramhound I just want to do that. Is it possibile? I'm just curious

Comment: @Allexj - Is it possible to view the encrypted data because that’s the only thing you can do if you don’t decrypt the data and you don’t need OpenSSL to view the data. I don’t answer questions when the purpose of the activity isn’t clear

Comment: fixed. basically I can achieve what I ask by using -nopad in decryption command, this way openssl does not check if padding is correct so it doesn't give "Bad decrypt" but instead gives me the decrypted output